# .NET Core Controller inheritance

Tags: json, inheritance, .net-core

I looked for this question, and altough there are similar questions asked, I could not find an answer.

So I have a problem. I have 2 classes:

```
public class Person {
public string name{ get; set; }
}

public class Doctor: Person{
public string specialization{ get; set; }
}
```

And I have controller:

```
[HttpPost]
...
public virtual IActionResult PostPerson([FromBody]Person person)
        { ... }
```

How can I make it so that if I send JSON like this:

```
{"specialization":"obgyn"}
```

that I get Doctor object in my controller?

Do  I need to make custom binding (is there an example? however I have much much more classes like this (100ts) so I would not like to do it for each class specifically) or set JsonOptions in Startup.cs, or something third??

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think this is supported. I don't think this is a good idea either. I'd either have two actions, or one action with a RequestViewModel that is compatible with both `Person` and `Doctor`.

Comment: it is supported if you add 
opts.SerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling=Newtonsoft.Json.TypeNameHandling.All; to your config and specify a type when sending JSON object... but I think another solution would be better

Comment: interesting. Feel free to add an answer if you manage to get this working!

Answer (score 0):

So the way to get this working is t oadd in your Startup.cs file a JSonOptions:

```
opts.SerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.TypeNameHandling.All;
```

This would then add $type properties to response, and would also read $type from incoming Json Messages. Unfortunatly, my clients wish changed because he does not want to identify the class by that field, but a custom another one, so this solution is not for me, but the answer my still help someone